# different font thickness - same settings / Tumblr and self-hosted

Tags: css, font-face, tumblr, webfonts

I use the same font on all my websites, with the same settings. Two are hosted on Tumblr: [kuuunst.com](http://kuuunst.com) / [allipossess.com](http://allipossess.com) and the other two are self-hosted on Strato [simonfreund.com](http://simonfreund.com) / [countless.info](http://countless.info).

For some reason the font on both Tumblr websites looks thinner (normal / how I want it to be) than on the other two websites, although the settings are the same:

```css
  font-family: 'tt0596m_', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.35;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
```

Any idea why that is and what I could try to change this?

Answer (score 3):

I have added a bunch of styles I didn't know and boom, the font looks nice and sharp on all websites...

here is what I have added:

```css
  body {
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-family: 'Monospace 821';
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.35;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-style: normal;
  speak: none;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: normal;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

I start believing it had to do with the `text-rendering` and `webkit-font-smoothing`, which are things I've never used / heard before...

Anyway, it´s solved now.